# Make div contained inside the grand parent?

Tags: javascript, html, css

Say I have 3 divs grandParent, Parent, and Child. Though parent's tag is inside the grandParent, using position: absolute; the parent is rendered outside the grandParent.
Now I have a child whose height and width is 100%, it is rendered outside the grandparent.
How to force the child to render inside the grandParent only. I want the green div to be fully inside the red div. And yellow div to remain partially outside the red div.

```html
<html>
   <head>
      <style> 
         .grandParent {
         width: 600px;
         height: 700px;
         background-color:red;
         }
         .parent {
         position: absolute;
         left: 0px;
         top: 0px;
         width: 360px;
         height: 275px;
         background-color: yellow;
         border: 2px solid yellow;
         transform: translate(417px, -88px) rotate(
         0deg
         );
         }
         .child {
         height: 275px;
         background-color: green;
         }
      </style>
   </head>
   </head>
   </head>
   <body>
      <div class="grandParent">
         <div class="parent">
            <div class="child">
            </div>
         </div>
      </div>
   </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use `position: relative;` for the grand parent div. Like this code:

```
.grandParent {
    width: 600px;
    height: 700px;
    background-color: red;
    position: relative; /* add this line */
}

.parent {
    position: absolute;
    left: 0px;
    top: 0px;
    width: 360px;
    height: 275px;
    background-color: yellow;
    border: 2px solid yellow; 
    transform: translate(227px, 9px) rotate(0deg); /* modify this line */
}
```

Read the [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/position) for the div positioning.

Comment: The wrong answer, I want to make a child div inside the grand parent div and this answer does not achieve the same.

Comment: You are about css or html?

Comment: if you are about html, you need just add div inside grandParent div next child div (child2). Like this: 
<body>  
     <div class="grandParent">
         <div class="parent">
            <div class="child"></div>
         </div>
         <!-- next child div--> <div class="child2"></div>
      </div>
</body>

Answer (score 0):

I was able to achieve this by setting absolute positioning on the child div. Note that I have set arbitrary values to get the child div inside the grandparent div separated from the parent div. Make sure you set the desired width on the child div.

```html
<html>
   <head>
      <style> 
         .grandParent {
         width: 600px;
         height: 700px;
         background-color:red;
         }
         .parent {
         position: absolute;
         left: 0px;
         top: 0px;
         width: 360px;
         height: 275px;
         background-color: yellow;
         border: 2px solid yellow;
         transform: translate(417px, -88px) rotate(
         0deg
         );
         }
         .child {
         position: absolute; /* add from here */
         left: -370px;
         top: 100px;
         width: 360px; /* to here */
         height: 275px;
         background-color: green;
         }
      </style>
   </head>
   </head>
   </head>
   <body>
      <div class="grandParent">
         <div class="parent">
            <div class="child">
            </div>
         </div>
      </div>
   </body>
</html>
```